# In Excel, I'm trying to copy a worksheet based on dropdown box selection and rename it but I have trouble with hidden sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a workbook with several worksheets I'm using as templates.  The goal is to copy, via a dropdown box selection, one of these sheets and rename the new sheet based on input the user types. I also want to place the new sheet name in a specific cell of the new sheet.

The following works, but hidden sheets cause problems  - if one sheet is hidden, the last sheet is renamed and another, hidden, sheet is created named (copied sheet name)2.

I'm also adding the new sheet name to a specific cell on the new sheet.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Range("g7")

    Case "Rooftop Unit"

    'Make a copy of Rooftop Unit sheet and rename it to what the user inputs
    Dim Newname As String
    Newname = InputBox("PLEASE ENTER EQUIPMENT NUMBER")
    If Newname <> "" Then
               
        Sheets("Roof Top Unit").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        ActiveSheet.Name = Newname
        
        Range("b11").Value = Newname
        
    End If
```

Comment: You can't activate a hidden worksheet. So instead of referring to `ActiveSheet.Name`, use `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name`.

Comment: You mean you get problems when the sheet to be copied ("Roof Top Unit") is hidden?

Comment: The Sheets.Count property returns the total number of sheets in a workbook, including both visible and hidden sheets. For a more accurate count that only includes visible sheets, consider using ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!    No, any time there is a hidden sheet it causes the issue I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy a sheet using the `Copy`-method, the new created sheet will get the active sheet. However, when a hidden sheet is copied, the copy will also be hidden and therefore cannot be active - you will need a different way to identify it.

Basically, I see 2 possibilities. The first is to temporarily make the source sheet visible. I suggest you use a function to copy the sheet (the function will return the new sheet, so you can do other stuff with it if you want):

```
Function copySheet(sourceSheet As Worksheet, newName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim sheetVisibility As XlSheetVisibility
    sheetVisibility = sourceSheet.Visible
    sourceSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    
    With sourceSheet.Parent
        sourceSheet.Copy after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    End With
    Set copySheet = ActiveSheet
    copySheet.Name = newName
    sourceSheet.Visible = sheetVisibility  ' If sheet was hidden, hide it again
End Function
```

The alternative would be to assume that the new sheet would get the name of the copied sheet with a suffix `" (2)"` (eg `"Roof Top Unit (2)"`)

```
Function copySheet(sourceSheet As Worksheet, newName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = sourceSheet.Parent
    Dim tmpName As String
    tmpName = sourceSheet.Name & " (2)"
    
    sourceSheet.Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Set copySheet = wb.Sheets(tmpName)
    copySheet.Name = newName
    copySheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible  ' Show the new sheet 
End Function
```

**Update** Put the function code in a regular modul. It would work also if you put it into the worksheet modul (where your current event routine is located), but usually it is better to have only event routines in the worksheet modules.

Your code could look like this:

```
Select Case Range("g7")
    Case "Rooftop Unit"
        Dim Newname As String
        Newname = InputBox("PLEASE ENTER EQUIPMENT NUMBER")
        If Newname = "" Then Exit Sub
        copySheet Sheets("Roof Top Unit"), Newname
```

Or, if you want to do something with the sheet in the following code:

```
        Dim newSheet as Worksheet
        Set newSheet = copySheet(Sheets("Roof Top Unit"), Newname)
```

NB: You probably want to rethink your logic. Your current routine will be triggered if the user switches to another sheet in the workbook. But this is out of scope for this question, if you are not sure about events and you can't figure it out, maybe you need to raise a new question.

Comment: Thank you!  As a novice to this scripting, I have no idea where to put this new function or how to integrate it with my current code.  FunThomas, can you offer advice?

Comment: Much appreciated.  I'll look into the event  / trigger issue.  Thanks!